# How can I adjust gradients for text while designing in the browser?

Tags: html, css, web, png

Lately I have been practicing more on designing in the browser and using pure code instead of images for effects.  I have used and seen several ways on how to add a gradient to text for a website such as:

(This step however uses a `.png` transparent image)

```
h1 {
  font: bold 330%/100% "Lucida Grande";
  position: relative;
  color: #464646;
}
h1 span {
  background: url(gradient.png) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31px;
}
```

and the pure code option:

```
h1 {  
        position: relative;  
        font-size: 70px;  
        margin-top: 0;  
        font-family: 'Lobster', helvetica, arial;  
    }  

    h1 a {  
        text-decoration: none;  
        color: #666;  
        position: absolute;  

        -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));  
    }  

    h1:after {  
        content : 'Hello World';  
        color: #d6d6d6;  
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;  
    }
```

but I was curious to know:

1. How can I adjust the location of the gradient?
2. Is there an easier way to code this for all comparable browsers (excluding IE)?

I have reviewed a few prior posts but nothing in regards to adjusting the gradient:

- [Is there a way to create a cross-browser, pure CSS3 text color gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740033/pure-css3-text-color-gradient-is-it-possible)
- [CSS3 Gradients not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097529/css3-gradients-not-working)
- [CSS3 animation with gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654510/css3-animation-with-gradients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adjust the location of the gradient, you'd have to edit the following line (not exactly sure where):

```
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,.5)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
```

A super cool tool that helps with this is the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It's helped me many times in the past. It even creates all the browser specific styles. Might be a good place to start.